# request.Request to delete a gitlab branch does not work but works using curl DELETE

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am trying to delete a git branch from gitlab, using the [gitlab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#authentication) with a [personal access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#personal-access-tokens).

If I use curl like this:

```
curl --request DELETE --header "PRIVATE_TOKEN: somesecrettoken" "deleteurl"
```

then it works and the branch is deleted.

But if I use `requests` like this:

```
token_data = {'private_token': "somesecrettoken"}
requests.Request("DELETE", url, data= token_data)
```

it doesn't work; the branch is not deleted.

Comment: Please do include what happens instead. I'm presuming that you use a `requests.send()` or `session.send()` call to send the `Request` object after preparing? Do include the response code and response body too.

Comment: Specifically, when there is a problem, then [Gitlab gives you a 4xx response with JSON body](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#data-validation-and-error-reporting). Can you edit your question to show what `response.status_code` is and what `response.json()` contains? You can use `pprint.pprint()` to format the response data nicely (or I can do this for you if you post the `response.json()` result)

Comment: Actually, I am trying to reproduce your issue and I can't. When I use `requests.delete(url, data=token_data)`, GitLab is being flexible enough to allow for that to work. Perhaps your *actual problem* is how you are using the `requests.Request()` instance? Creating that instance *doesn't actually send anything*, you'll have to do pass the instance to `requests.send()` (or via a session). Is this *all* of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requests code is indeed not doing the same thing. You are setting `data=token_data`, which puts the token in the request body. The `curl` command-line uses a *HTTP header* instead, and leaves the body empty.

Do the same in Python:

```
token_data = {'Private-Token': "somesecrettoken"}
requests.Request("DELETE", url, headers=token_data)
```

You can also put the token in the URL parameters, via the `params` argument:

```
token_data = {'private_token': "somesecrettoken"}
requests.Request("DELETE", url, params=token_data)
```

This adds `?private_token=somesecrettoken` to the URL sent to gitlab.

**However**, GitLab does accept the `private_token` value in the request body **as well**, either as form data or as JSON. Which means that you are using the requests API wrong.

A `requests.Request()` instance is not going to be sent without additional work. It is normally [only needed if you want to access the prepared data before sending](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#prepared-requests).

If you don't need to use this more advanced feature, use the `requests.delete()` method:

```
response = requests.delete(url, headers=token_data)
```

If you *do* need the feature, use a [`requests.Session()` object](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects), then first prepare the request object, then send it:

```
with requests.Session() as session:
    request = requests.Request("DELETE", url, params=token_data)
    prepped = request.prepare()
    response = session.send(prepped)
```

Even without needing to use prepared requests, a session is very helpful when using an API. You can set the token *once*, on a session:

```
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers['Private-Token'] = 'somesecrettoken'

    # now all requests via the session will use this header
    response = session.get(url1)
    response = session.post(url2, json=....)
    response = session.delete(url3)
    # etc.
```

Comment: I tried `requests.Request("DELETE", url, headers=token_data)` it did not worked

Comment: I `requests.Request("DELETE", url, headers=token_data)`  returns response that does not have status_code method which is weird. instead it has methods `files, headers, json. , prepare, json_hook, url `

Comment: @ChangZhao: you are looking at the `Request` instance (the `.prepare()` method is a clue), not the response produced when you send your request to the server. You *are* sending the `Request()` object with code you haven't posted in your question, right?